# Is there some specific way to access strings in C multidimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to C, I'm trying to implement an arrays of a struct. But for some reason I can't seem to get my finger on, when I try to access the data in the array struct by printing it to the console it simply doesn't execute. This happened in a windows environment, so I changed and went to linux. It simply puts up a segmentation fault and halts. I've dug around and it seems that my syntax is on point, yet I can't seem to shake the error off. One website I visited was https://www.javatpoint.com/array-of-structures-in-c but still my code won't work. Here's my C file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
  char registration_number[15];
  char forename[20];
  char surname[25];
  char department[60];
  char gender;
};

int main(void) { 
  struct student student_record[5];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Student %i", i);
    printf("\nInput student forename: ");
    scanf("%s",&student_record[i].forename);
    printf("\nInput student surname: ");
    scanf("%s",&student_record[i].surname);
    printf("\nInput student registration number: ");
    scanf("%s",&student_record[i].registration_number);
    printf("\nInput student department: ");
    scanf("%s",&student_record[i].department);
    printf("\nInput student gender: ");
    scanf("%s",&student_record[i].gender);
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("Reg No. \t First Name \t Last Name \t Gender \t Department \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%s \t %s \t %s \t %s \t %s \n", student_record[i].registration_number, student_record[i].forename, student_record[i].surname, student_record[i].gender, student_record[i].department );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%s",&student_record[i].gender);`  => `scanf("%c",&student_record[i].gender);`

```
printf("%s \t %s \t %s \t %c \t %s \n", /*cut*/, student_record[i].gender, student_record[i].department );
```

Comment: Damn. My bad.. I did not eve notice that at all. Thanks

Comment: I was also wondering if you could please tell me why my input loop seems to skip over gender when I switch from %s to %c?

Comment: dump all values and see why. It is aperfect way of learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues in your code.

The `scanf()` expects a pointer and an array of type converted to pointer of type but there are few exceptions to this rule and one of them is when used unary `&` operator i.e. when passed this `&student_record[i].forename` to `scanf()` it does not convert to pointer. The type of `&student_record[i].forename` argument is `char (*)[20]` and with `%s` format specifier, `scanf()` expects `char *` type argument.
So, when passed array to `scanf()`, you don't need to give `&`. You should also specify the maximum field width for the conversion specifier `%s` in the format string of `scanf()` to ensure that it should not access the buffer beyond it's size. The maximum field width should be one less than the size of array to accommodate the terminating null byte.
It should be:

```
    scanf("%19s", student_record[i].forename);
    scanf("%24s", student_record[i].surname);
    scanf("%14s", student_record[i].registration_number);
    scanf("%59s", student_record[i].department);
```

The type of `gender` member of `student` structure is `char` and you are using `%s` format specifier in `scanf()` to read it. This will lead to undefined behaviour as the `scanf()` adds terminating null character when it read a string to a buffer. Since, the `gender` field size is one byte, the `scanf()` end up accessing memory beyond the `gender` field size. You should use `%c` format specifier in `scanf()` for reading `gender` field value. The `%c` conversion specifier won't automatically skip any leading whitespace, so if there's a stray newline in the input stream (from a previous entry) the `scanf()` call will consume it immediately. One work around of this problem is to put a blank space before the conversion specifier in the format string passed to `scanf()`.

```
    scanf(" %c", &student_record[i].gender);
```

Make sure to give correct format specifier for `gender` field in `printf()` as well:

```
    printf("%s \t %s \t %s \t %c \t %s \n", student_record[i].registration_number, student_record[i].forename, student_record[i].surname, student_record[i].gender, student_record[i].department );
                             ^^^^
```

Also, the way you are printing the column names and the structure fields, the output may not be in proper alignment. Instead, you should use the width with format specifiers in `printf()` and left align it (refer some good reference material for `printf()` family function for more information on this), like this:

```
  printf("%-15s %-20s %-25s %-6s %-60s \n", "Reg No.", "First Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "Department");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%-15s %-20s %-25s %-6c %-60s \n", student_record[i].registration_number, student_record[i].forename, student_record[i].surname, student_record[i].gender, student_record[i].department );
  }
```